# using AND or OR function after/before a BETWEEN in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using a query like

`WHERE this.ID BETWEEN 1 AND 11`

but I want to add another ID to this like

`WHERE this.ID BETWEEN 1 AND 11 AND this.ID = 22`

or even

`WHERE this.ID = 22 AND this.ID BETWEEN 1 AND 11`

This causes an error.

Am I stuck with using `WHERE this.ID >= 1 AND this.ID <= 11 AND this.ID = 22`? Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: First there is a syntax error. You have two WHERE clauses

Comment: Im showing 2 different queries in that sentence, Ill edit it

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If ID is between 1 and 11, then at the same time it can not be equal to 22. If you want to pick all the `ID`'s which are in between 1 and 11 and you also need `ID` which is equal to 22. Then you have to use `OR` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use **AND**  it will check id is must equal  to 1 to 11 and 22.

Id can not have same time two value.

You should use **OR**. But when you use OR condition you must put it in **()**. so other condition will work properly.

you can add other condition after bracket.

```
WHERE (this.ID BETWEEN 1 AND 11 OR this.ID = 22)
```

Comment: I cant for 10 minutes, I will as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it on my shell

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE (id BETWEEN 1 AND 2) or (ID = 3)
```

This gives result with no error

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE (id BETWEEN 1 AND 2) AND (ID =3)
```

This give empty result with no error.

As you can see you are fetching result between two ids and also passing `AND` condition with different id the result will be empty